# What is a Maven repository?

Tags: maven, repository

I read on ["Introduction to Repositories"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) that

> A repository in Maven is used to hold build artifacts and dependencies of varying types.

By [browsing a remote Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse|842264825) I see that an artifact is apparently a *directory* satisfying some constraints, e.g. it must contain a file called `maven-metadata.xml` and a file called `<artifactId>-<version>.pom`. Both of those files have some schema and semantics. I also see that I have a "local repository" at `~/.m2/repository`. But the directory structure is different, e.g. there are no `maven-metadata.xml` files. So the remote repository and my local repository are encoding the same data in different ways.

But I'm obviously guessing, and neither the documentation, nor any other answers on SO, clear up my questions. So -- what *is* a Maven repository, in formal terms? And how is this encoded in remote repositories and local repositories?

Here's a guess at an answer:

> A repository is a map from *GAVs* to *build artifacts*. A GAV is a triple *(groupId, artifactId, version)* where each component is a string. A *build artifact* is a map from *filenames* to *file contents*.
>
> A repository supports two operations: `getBuildArtifact`, which takes a *GAV*  and returns the associated *build artifact* if the given *GAV* is mapped by the repository; and `putBuildArtifact`, which maps a provided *GAV* to a provided *build artifact*.
>
> [...]

Comment: Why do you expect answers if you answered your question already yourself. I don't know what you like to expect and for what purpose?

Comment: I *haven't* answered the question myself. It's a guess, to be corrected and expanded.

Answer (score 5):

jameshfisher,

First, you need to take care to differentiate between a local repository and a remote one.

Second, you're diving too deep into the implementation of certain Maven repositories without first establishing a high-level conceptual understanding of it.

Let's start with remote repositories. Basically, a Maven repo does to build artifacts (jars, wars, zips, poms, etc) what a Subversion repo does for source code: stores it centrally so that developers can efficiently share the output of their work in a way that ensures consistency, stability, and transparent version management.

Most artifacts can be identified through 3 GAV coordinates, such as `org.myproject + mylib + 1.0`.

But sometimes a single build will generate not only `mylib.jar`, but also `mylib-sources.jar` and `mylib.zip` all at the same time. Then you will need to pass in these additional qualifiers to locate those artifacts.

How the repository stores this under the hood is irrelevant, given there are at least 2 major implementations out there - Artifactory and Nexus. It's the API, not the implementation that matters, and as long as you specify the dependency section of your pom.xml file such that you can identify the desired artifact, I don't see why you need to know the underlying implementation.

Now let's look at local repositories. Yes, these are much simpler - basically a folder system that locally mirrors the GAV convention for storing jars on your local machine. Simply put, local repos are for caching artifacts so your builds are faster. If you had to visit Maven central for every dependency of every build, your builds would take forever and their server would probably be overwhelmed.

Instead, your local repo downloads the dependencies from Maven central once, and doesn't bother checking again (not quite true: SNAPSHOT dependencies will be rechecked once a day, or if you pass the "-U" flag, which adds considerable network activity and is why you should prefer release dependencies over snapshots where possible).

Anyway, the main point is that local repos is just caching mechanism for builds on that box. Remote repos is when you're ready to share artifacts with other people, who will then download it into their local repos for their builds.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re API vs implementation: that's a good distinction. By browsing the filesystem, I was trying to "reverse engineer" the implicit API, since a formal API doesn't appear to exist. My "guess at an answer" above is a stab at what an API description might look like. The data model would be extended with operations like `get : GAV -> Artifact` and `put : (GAV, Artifact) -> void`. I've since found "Aether" which claims to define an API, but it's *enormous* and apparently not Maven-specific.

Comment: The dependency section of pom.xml file is really the formal api. Did the above answer your question?